# css Mask won't follow scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, mask

I've searched everywhere, but I couldn't find anything on my problem.
I have a div with a mask inside on the bottom.

```css
#test {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 113;
  overflow-y: inherit;
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.00, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(0.35, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(0.50, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(0.85, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(1.00, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
```

The mask is nicely on the bottom of the clientHeight, but when I scroll with the keyboard keys the mask will not move...

Please help!

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle? :)

Comment: its a little difficult to do that

Comment: I am unable to recreate your issue, this is why I requested for that

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/odyjotp7/

Comment: its a little different, but same issue, the body scroll I want to work like the div scroll